# Do not include in the LoV the car numbers already used in the second table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have two tables, in one table “Car number”, I have a list of car numbers there. In the second table “Registered numbers” I have registered car numbers there. In the “Registered Numbers” table, I fill out the form using the LOV list taken from the “Number Table” table. Is it possible to make sure that in the form when filling out "Registered numbers" in the LOV list there are only those numbers that have not been registered before. Since now all the numbers from the “Car Number” table appear in the list. Thanks for the help)

```
CREATE TABLE number_car
id       NUMBER(10) ,
number   varcahar2(10),
date_add varcahar2(30)
);

CREATE TABLE registered_numbers
id           NUMBER(10) ,
reg_number   varcahar2(10),
date_reg     varcahar2(30)
);

select for form table  registered_numbers (LoV);
select number as num,number from number_car;
```

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` (or `NOT IN`) might help.

```
select c.car_number d,
       c.id     r
from number_car c
where not exists (select null 
                  from registered_numbers r
                  where r.id = c.id
                 )
order by c.car_number;
```

I *renamed* the `number` column to `car_number` as `number` is reserved for datatype name and can't be used as a column name (OK, it *can*, but it should not be. Hint: double quotes).

Comment: and we do not check the similarity column reg number?

Comment: No need if ID column does the job. If not, use whichever column you find appropriate. You posted two CREATE TABLE statements, no foreign keys, no column description so we can only guess what's what.

Comment: Littlefoot, thanks for the help!) You are very understanding in apex.  And you can help me with one more question, you may know how to implement it) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833684/change-the-color-of-the-sample-line-to-apex-oracle

Comment: You're welcome. Just in case you didn't notice, good practice here - on Stack Overflow - is to either upvote or accept answers you find useful.

Comment: Littlefoot, and it is possible to add the column "Used" in the table "number_car", and in the report "number_car" if the numbers are used in "registered_numbers" , to write opposite "Used" and if not, then "Not used" ??? My report request looks like this: "Select id , number, used, date_add from number_car"

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? `alter table` does that. However, I'd suggest you **not** to do that. Fetch that information from the `registered_numbers` table using (outer?) join.