# Change the color of the sample line to apex oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a table with a list of car numbers "Auto numbers". They are reflected in an interactive report. Some of these numbers are assigned to cars that are displayed on the second Info Cars table. Is it possible to somehow change the line color in the table with the list of car numbers "Auto numbers". You only need to change the row color for rows that have common numbers that are displayed in the Info Cars table.

Comment: Databases know nothing about colors.  You need to do this in the application layer.

Comment: It's an IR, use the Highlight row feature?

Comment: i can't figure out how to form a condition

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden column in the table "Auto numbers", in which you can display a sign if the number is in table "Cars table".
Next, use the line coloring, as shown [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3739809?start=0&tstart=0)
For example, use a hidden column as a class, in the column you need or otherwise so that you can access it through JQ / JS and do not forget.